# python socket proxy fails to intercept all data

Tags: python, sockets, proxy, http-proxy, python-sockets

I have the following python proxy (found it online and tweaked it to my needs) which is supposed to intercept communication between a java app and its server. The communication is done via HTTP which is then upgraded to standard sockets. My problem is that after the connection is upgraded, the communication stops every time after a certain amount of data was transferred. What am I missing here and why is the connection closing before all the data is sent/received?

Traffic capture with/without proxy:

[Without proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCsk2.png)
| [With proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQEh4.png)

My proxy:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time

changeport = False

def server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    try:
        server.bind(( local_host, local_port))
    except:
        print "[!!] Failed to listen on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port)
        sys.exit()

    print "[*] Listening on %s:%d" % (local_host, local_port)
    server.listen(5)

    while 1:
        client_socket, addr = server.accept()
        print "[==>] Received incoming connection from %s:%d" %(addr[0], addr[1])

        # start a thread to talk to the remote host
        if (changeport):
            proxy = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler, \
            args=(client_socket, remote_host, 1026, receive_first))
        else:
            proxy = threading.Thread(target=proxy_handler, \
            args=(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first))
        proxy.start()


def receive_from(connection):
    buffer = ''
    connection.settimeout(2)
    begin=time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - begin > 2:
            break
        try:
            data = connection.recv(8192)
            if data:
                buffer += data
            else:
                time.sleep(0.1)
        except:
            pass
    return buffer


def request_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    #buffer.replace("http://localhost" , "sw80.sw.qa.opsware.com")
    return buffer


def response_handler(buffer):
    # perform packet modifications
    return buffer


def hexdump(src, length=16):
    result = []
    digists = 4 if isinstance(src, unicode) else 2
    for i in range(len(src), length):
        s = src[i:i+length]
        hexa = b' '.join(['%0*X' % (digits, ord(x)) for x in s])
        text = b''.join([x if 0x20 <= ord(x) < 0x7F else b'.' for x in s])
        result.append(b"%04X %-*s %s" % (i, length*(digits + 1), hexa, text))


def proxy_handler(client_socket, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first):
    global changeport
    remote_socket = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    remote_socket.connect(( remote_host, remote_port ))
    remote_socket.setblocking(0)
    if receive_first:
        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        #hexdump(remote_buffer)
        remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)

        # if we have data to send to client, send it:
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print "[<==] Sending %d bytes to localhost." %len(remote_buffer)
            print remote_buffer
            #hexdump(remote_buffer)
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)

    while 1:
        local_buffer = receive_from(client_socket)
        if len(local_buffer):
            print "[==>] Received %d bytes from localhost." % len(local_buffer)
            print local_buffer
            #hexdump(local_buffer)
            local_buffer = request_handler(local_buffer)
            remote_socket.send(local_buffer)
            print "[==>] Sent to remote."

        remote_buffer = receive_from(remote_socket)
        if len(remote_buffer):
            print "[==>] Received %d bytes from remote." % len(remote_buffer)
            print remote_buffer
            #hexdump(remote_buffer)
            if "DDEA0ABBFD43FC832BE3D7950190C9BE" in remote_buffer:
                print "CHANGING REMOTE PORT TO 1026"
                changeport = True
            remote_buffer = response_handler(remote_buffer)
            client_socket.send(remote_buffer)
            print "[==>] Sent to localhost."

        if not len(local_buffer) or not len(remote_buffer):
            client_socket.close()
            remote_socket.close()
            print "[*] No more data. Closing connections"
            break



def main():
    if len(sys.argv[1:]) != 5:
        print "Usage: ./proxy.py <localhost> <localport> <remotehost> <remoteport> <receive_first>"
        print "Example: ./proxy.py 127.0.0.1 9000 10.12.122.1 9999 True"
        sys.exit()

    local_host = sys.argv[1]
    local_port = int(sys.argv[2])
    remote_host = sys.argv[3]
    remote_port = int(sys.argv[4])

    if sys.argv[5] == 'True':
        receive_first = True
    else:
        receive_first = False

    server_loop(local_host, local_port, remote_host, remote_port, receive_first)
main()
```